# how can I customize file name in python MIMEImage?

Tags: python, email, smtp

I'm using python SMTP to send an email with pictures attachment.

```
for parent, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(base_path):
    for file in filenames:
        with open(base_path+file, 'rb') as fp:
            img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
        msg.attach(img)
# Send email
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, 25)
# server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.login(from_addr, password)
server.sendmail(from_addr, [to_addr], msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

However, when I receive the email I send, the pictures seem to be renamed to other generated names such as ATT00002.jpg, ATT00003.jpg etc.
How can I keep the original picture names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the below code.This will solve your problem

```
for file in filenames:
    with open(base_path+file, 'rb') as fp:
        img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    img.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % file)
    msg.attach(img)
```

You need to add header to the MIME PART.

Comment: @bad_day_out : Please accept it as an answer if it helped you